# exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened

Tags: wpf, manifest

I have an error when publishing my WPF app in my visual studio 2019. It was working fine before But i didnt know what happen.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.19045.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
    clr.dll             : 4.8.9167.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.19041.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/HRIS_PUBLISH/HRIS.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : HRIS.application, Version=1.0.0.63, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d197551de66625b, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\HRIS_PUBLISH\HRIS.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/HRIS_PUBLISH/Application%20Files/HRIS_1_0_0_63/HRIS.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:     
        + Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [09/15/2023 6:56:54 pm] : Activation of C:\HRIS_PUBLISH\HRIS.application has started.
    * [09/15/2023 6:56:54 pm] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [09/15/2023 6:56:54 pm] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [09/15/2023 6:56:54 pm] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/HRIS_PUBLISH/Application%20Files/HRIS_1_0_0_63/HRIS.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:     
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Ive tried using Mage to know what is the problem but nothing works. I dont know what to do please help me.